# In jqgrid, how do I change a value just before edit cell?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to find out if there is a nice way in JQGrid to change the value of a cell just before it is edited.

What I want to accoplish is that a cell holds some data and some markup, so the value is something along the lines

```
<div style="font-size:8px">10%</div><div style="font-size:10px">100</div>
```

But when the user clicks on the data I only want to display

```
10
```

Currently when I edit it I see the whole markup and everything and I would like to hide that with some quick parsing just before the edit event.

When I tried changeing the value in

```
beforeEditCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol)
```

with

```
setCell (rowid, colname, data, class, properties, forceup)
```

The change didn't seem to affect the content in the input field that is opened. My thesis is that the value produced for the input field maybe is put in a variable before "beforeEditCell" is triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to the event `formatCell`, jqGrid documentation says :

> applies only to a cell that is editable; this event allows formatting the cell content before editing, and returns the formatted value

I think is the best way to achieve what you want.

Comment: This looks exactly like the thing I need. I will verify. Thank you.

Comment: It was perfect for my use case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use,
    unformat: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
      return cellvalue;
    },

To the custom unformat function are passed the following parameters:
cellvalue - is the value to be unformated (pure text).
options - is an object containing the following element
options : { rowId: rid, colModel: cm} where rowId - is the id of the row colModel is the object of the properties for this column getted from colModel array of jqGrid
cellobject - is a jQuery cell object. This object can be used to obtain different things from the cell element - by example jQuery(cellobject).html() can be used to get the html content instead of the text.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score -2):

I use jquery to change the value of the edit cells.

```
$("#cellid").val("10");
```